# How to access a private variable in a class without using allocation?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to better understand the memory allocation / pointers etc..

As you can see on "test" Method , I tried to access the Name of `CTest class` so that I can fill it in my `Schedule array` . Is there a possiblity to access the CTest class without allocation `( CTest * Test = new CTest(); )` . I mean is it possible to use here only pointers to access the variable `Name` of `CTest` ?

This is my program :

```
class CTest
{
    public:
    void setName(std::string str){ Name = str;}
    std::string getName(){return Name;}

    private:
    std::string Name;
};

class CEvent
{
public:
    CEvent() = default;
    void setTestName(std::string str){Test->setName(str);}
    std::string getTestName(){return Test->getName();}
     ~CEvent(){};
private:
    std::string Name;
    CTest *Test = new CTest();   //Here
};

class CBlock
{
public:
    CBlock() = default;
    friend class CBooking;
    ~CBlock(){}

private:
    CEvent *Schedule[7][5];
};

class CBooking
{
public:
    CBooking() = default;
    void test();
    ~CBooking(){}

private:
    CBlock *Sched;
};

void CBooking::test()
{ 
   Sched = new CBlock();
   Sched->Schedule[3][2] = new CEvent();

   std::string a = "test2";
   Sched->Schedule[3][2]->setTestName(a);

   std::cout << Sched->Schedule[3][2]->getTestName();
}

int main()
{
    CBooking a;
    a.test();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you don't want `new`, don't use `new`. Just declare a `CTest`. Can you clarify the problem? What is forcing dynamic allocation here? I don't see it.

Comment: For `CTest`, just change `CTest *Test = ...` to `CTest Test;` and `Test->` to `Test.`

Comment: I extracted this from my real program . Concerning Sched->Schedule[3][2] = new CEvent();  I'm actually trying to fill this array with different variables from CEvent , in my program I have like 5 private variables that I filled them in the array. The problem is that I'm using a lot of memory and I wanted to somehow change the idea

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "without allocation". `Name` is a non-static data member of `CTest`, meaning you need to have a `CTest` object to hold the name. That can be done with `CTest *test = new CTest();` or `CTest test;`, but in both cases you're allocating memory for that object. Unless you mean giving your `CEvent` object a pointer to an existing `CTest` object?

Comment: @Kevin exactly that's what I mean. Sorry for my bad explanation . I want to give my CEvent object (Schedule) a pointer to an existing CTest object . Which means I won't need to allocate memory everytime when I need to assign the private variables of CTest to CEvent Schedule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to give `CEvent` an existing `CTest` object then pass it as a reference in the constructor:

```
class CEvent
{
public:
    CEvent(CTest &test): test(test) {}

    void setTestName(std::string str){test.setName(str);}
    std::string getTestName(){return test.getName();}
private:
    CTest &test;
};

...

CTest test;
CEvent event(test);
event.setTestName("test");
std::cout << event.getTestName() << "\n";
```

If you want to be able to copy/move `CEvent` objects around (or change the `CTest` object one is holding) you'll need to make the `test` member a pointer rather than a reference, e.g. `CTest *test;` and initialize it in the constructor like this: `CEvent(CTest &test): test(&test) {}`. It's still a good idea to pass it to the constructor as a reference to ensure that it won't be null.

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution but a question : what if CTest was an abstract class  ?

Comment: Because if I set CTest  as an abstract class I get  these errors : `error: cannot declare variable 'test' to be of abstract type 'CTest'`
    `CTest test;`
          ^~~~
`output.cpp:6:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within 'CTest':
 class CTest`
`output.cpp:10:13: note: virtual int CTest::print()' virtual print() = 0;`

Comment: Oops, ignore my previous comment. I thought you said if `CEvent` was abstract :)

Comment: You would just need to create a concrete object of a class deriving from `CTest` and pass *that* to your `CEvent` object's constructor instead. e.g. `DerivedCTest test; CEvent event(test);`.